# Reading autoshapes from excel using java

Tags: java, excel, using, shapes

I have to read an excel sheet full of flowcharts(ovals,different types of connectors etc) in java.I tried libraries like apache poi,jxl,jxls.From these apache poi,jxl are ruled out coz they dont really support excel autoshapes.I am not sure about jxls.I have gone through its api but i am not sure if it can serve my purpose.Hence i need some expertise.If autoshapes can be read using jxls please provide me some sample code.Any help would be a life saver.Also if possi let me know if there are any paid libraries serving this purpose(Aspose.Cells is one but it doesnt support connnectors.)...Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The only reasonable solution would be using Com4J, with an Excel binding, and then controlling an Excel ActiveX instance to read the data from it. This is so native to Excel that you won't be able to do it without excel. Eventually you can do this by remoting OpenOfice (has a native Java Binding!).

Comment: hey daniel thanx for your reply....i am a newbie in this matter so plz can u explain me what u meant by saying 'wont be able to do it without excel'...did u mean that reading excel to the fullest wont be possible unless you use microsoft technologies like C#..?Coz the place of deployment of our application is gona be a LINUX server...so we cant use any of the microsoft technologies...

Comment: I meant this. But if you can open your Excel sheet with OpenOffice and see the word art, you will be able to use the OpenOffice Java connector to modify it.